# Create KML route

Tags: kml

I am trying to create a route based off lon & lat's.  This is what i have so far, but it doesn't seem to be working correctly.

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2"> 
<Document>
  <PlaceMark>
    <name>test</name>
    <description>test Desc</description>
    <Point>
      <coordinates>-80.54400115,43.4250264</coordinates>
      <coordinates>-80.52674314,43.43127701</coordinates>
      ...
    </Point>
    </PlaceMark>
  </Document>
<kml>
```

Is the syntax correct?  When i load it up in my maps app, it doesn't show the route.

Answer (score 3):

Please see the [KML reference](https://developers.google.com/kml/documentation/kmlreference)

1. KML is XML which is case sensitive (PlaceMark is not the same as Placemark)
2. a `<Point>` is a single location
3. a line is a `<LineString>`
4. Your XML needs to be valid (`</kml>` is needed to close the opening `<kml>`).

[example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GoogleEx_layer-kml_linktoB.html?filename=http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/SO_LineStringA.kml)

[KML from example above on Google Maps](https://maps.google.com/maps?q=http%3a%2F%2Fwww.geocodezip.com%2Fgeoxml3_test%2FSO_LineStringA.kml&hl=en&sll=32.824552,-117.108978&sspn=0.691256,0.883026&t=h&z=13)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2">         <Document>
<Placemark><name>test</name>
<description>test Desc</description>
<LineString>
<coordinates>
-80.54400115,43.4250264
-80.52674314,43.43127701
-80.5274517,43.43458707
-80.53223781,43.43876923
-80.54385782,43.44993036
-80.53949137,43.45723788
-80.53950793,43.46780893
-80.53352615,43.4730443
-80.53491389,43.47816267
-80.54136061,43.48417145
-80.54163034,43.48439869
</coordinates>
</LineString>
</Placemark></Document>
</kml>
```

Comment: Thanks.  for some reason only one point is shown, not the whole route.

Comment: For you in my example or on your map? If your map where is the KML file.

Comment: I just used your example and it didn't show the line string only one point.

Comment: Is there an online application that you can upload a kml file to validate ?

Comment: humm doesn't seeem to work.  I don't know why i can't get a linstring drawn.

Comment: Can you provide a link to your KML?